# QGIS WPS plugin misses one parameter

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-plugins, web-service, wps

I set up a Web Processing Service with 52°North and GRASS (using the wps-grass-bridge). All went smooth and I get a proper DescribeProcess for i.cluster. As you can see, I need to give the parameter "classes":

[image: Part of the DescribeProcess-request]

I installed Horst Duester's WPS plugin for QGIS and wanted to test my WPS now. Surprisingly I get all paramters as fields to fill beside of the obligatory "classes". It is just missing. 
Does anybody have an idea what is wrong here?

[image: Screenshot of obligatory fields in the QGIS WPS plugin]

Comment: Consider to contact the author(s)...